# TempleOS sound with VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, audio, templeos

I'm currently running TempleOS v5.03 with Virtual Box 5.2. I don't believe sound is working. When I play a God Song with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>, or go under the Jukebox and play a song nothing seems to generate sound. What configuration must I have in my Virtual Box to get sound working? **My laptop does not have a PC Speaker.**

It seems [others have had this problem too](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-virtualization-and-cloud-90/internal-pc-speakers-in-virtualbox-4175470322/)

Comment: So, here's the odd thing. What Evan's doing is entirely within the rules. Wasting your own time is *literally* fine, even if its an OS written by someone who... [quite literally seems to be a little crazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TempleOS) . And here's the thing. Assuming good intent, and not arguing with Evan about whether this is a waste of his time, free or otherwise... is probably the most productive thing to do. I'm sure that if we engage constructively (or not at all), any issues we have will sort themselves out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Sound Driver Emulation of PC Speaker

**This only works on Linux.** My sound card happens to be `snd_hda_intel`, that driver actually can emulate a PC Speaker itself with the `beep_mode` parameter:

> `beep_mode`: Select HDA Beep registration mode (`0`=off, `1`=on) (default=`1`). (array of bool)

**Moreover it's on by default**.

### Set-Up and Configuration

You'll have to set up the permissions once -- adding yourself to the proper group. Without this, you'll get an [error like this in your `VBox.log`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/448276/3285)

1. Ensure the `pcspkr` module is loaded with `lsmod | grep pcspkr`, if you don't see it, load it

   ```
   sudo modprobe pcspkr
   ```

   This will expose a device file `/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr`
2. Ensure that your group can write to the device file exposed above (`ls -lah`). On Ubuntu it's owned by `input`, for this you'll have to run something like

   ```
   usermod -aG input "$USER"
   ```
3. **Now, log off and log back in**
4. Verify that you're in that right group by running `groups` which will tell what groups your user is in

### Confirm setup was successful

From now on you just need to do the following,

1. Run `modprobe pcspkr`, you'll have to do this every time or remove `pcskr` from your blacklist so it's added on boot. I just run it **before** I start virtual box.
2. Run `xkbbell` or in `xterm` (I wouldn't use gnome-terminal, or xfce-terminal, or konqueror for this because they may swallow it) run `printf "\a"` if you do not hear anything then run the following and try again

   ```
   xset b 100
   # or whatever the source control is for the beeper
   amixer sset Beep 100%
   ```

### Lastly, you'll have to enable PC Speaker pass-through,

For the last step, you'll need to enable PC Speaker pass-through from the [VirtualBox *Advanced FAQ*](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html), you can do this with `VBoxManage`. The GUI has yet no method to accomplish this.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/i8254/0/Config/PassthroughSpeaker" 100
```

Now you just have to the following from now on,

**That's it.** Now just startup Virtual box and launch TempleOS. You should be able to play God Songs. You do not need to reinstall TempleOS.

## No Sound Driver Emulation of PC Speaker

I believe this is **only** possible in one of two ways, hypothetically

- If the host operating system can virtualize a PC Speaker which Virtual Box can pass through. I believe PC Speakers can be passed through with Virtual Box **on Linux**. I have yet to find anything that can emulate a PC Speaker on the host and work with something like `beep` though. If this can be made functional, then something like this should do the pass-through. From the [VirtualBox *Advanced FAQ*](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html)

  ```
  VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/i8254/0/Config/PassthroughSpeaker" 100
  ```

  I asked a question on this on Unix.SE, [*Can Pulse Audio emulate a virtual PC Speaker?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/443028/3285)
- If Virtual Box can emulate a PC Speaker which it can not currently do, afaik.

I don't think there is a solution or much attention to this as even for older DOS Systems that used PWM on the PC Speaker, support for Sound Blaster was ubiquitous and Virtual Box can emulate a sound-blaster compatible device.